# Is it possible to delete media from ipod library programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ipod, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

After search several apple documents and websites, I feel that apple only allow to read media data from ipod-library.
 Is there anyone confirm about this ?
 Is it possible to implement the feature to delete media from ipod library ?

Regards,
Soontak Lee

Answer (score 0):

No, if someone shows you the hack still I would not recommend as your app will be likely to get rejected by Apple. It's a violation of sandboxing. An app does not have power to add or delete from data from another's app's sandbox.

Would you feel okay if third party app developer creates an app which lets user deletes data from your app?